# Angular2 HTML Element Carousel

Tags: angular, carousel

Does someone know a good carousel library for angular2?

Such as https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular2/ons-carousel-item.html but just the carousel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [Angular2-drag-scroll](https://github.com/bfwg/angular2-drag-scroll), it has features like mouse drag to scroll and hide scrollbar etc.

Usage example:

```
<div drag-scroll drag-scroll-y-disabled="true" scrollbar-hidden="true" >
  <img *ngFor="let image of imagelist" [src]="'you_assets_path' + image" />
</div>
```

[image: Scroll]

For more documentation, there a demo site: https://bfwg.github.io/angular2-drag-scroll/

Answer (score 1):

No need to be worried for "which carousel  I should use?" Go with any carousel  You like e.g. bootstrap carousel , jQuery carousel , owl carousel etc.

Angular2 does not bind you with any specific library, it will automatically update its changes (not like Angular1).

I was using it as follows(just Bootstrap carousel):

```
             <section class="learning-carousel pad-t-1 row" *ngIf="!coursesLding && itsCoursesLstDta && itsCoursesLstDta.length">
                  <div class="clearfix carousel-ms carousel slide myCrsalBook" tabindex="0" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                      <div *ngFor="let item of itsCoursesLstDta;let ind=index;" [ngClass]="{'item carousel-item':true,active: ind==curCourse}">
                        <div class="course-card panel">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" [ngClass]="{'active':item.job_starred && !appState.get('isNotLoggedIn'),'btn-favorite pull-right':true}" (click)="starItm(''+item.id,item.job_starred,'courses');item.job_starred=!item.job_starred;"><i class="fa"></i></a>
                          <a [href]="'http://'+item.baseUrl" target="_blank">
                            <img [src]="item.imgUrl" width="85px" />
                          </a>
                          <a [href]="'http://'+item.baseUrl" target="_blank">
                            <p class="course-title" [innerHTML]="item.title"></p>
                          </a>
                          <p class="course-description" [innerHTML]="item.description" style="max-height: 100px;overflow-y: auto;"></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <a [ngStyle]="{visibility: curCourse==0?'hidden':'visible'}" class="left carousel-control" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" data-slide="prev" (click)="curCourse=curCourse-1">
                      <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-prev"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a [ngStyle]="{visibility: curCourse==(itsCoursesLstDta.length-1)?'hidden':'visible'}" class="right carousel-control" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" data-slide="next" (click)="curCourse=curCourse+1">
                      <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-next"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </section>
```

Inside controller:

```
jQuery(".myCrsalBook").carousel({interval: false});
```

Thats it is was working. :)